# 2.8 object not showing in preview and render

Tags: rendering

Hello everyone just testing out 2.8 V. I have stumbled with the tipical nooby thingy "object not showing in render and preview", any advice and help will be appreciated.
image attached if anything else is needed please let me know.
original file was a 2.79 version file. i this helps.

thnx a lot!

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you add the blend file to your question? Grab the URL of the question
Go to https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/
Select the blend file
Add the url of the question
Grab the url that results
Go back to the question and edit it

Add the new url to the bottom of the post

Comment: OK,   I found a solution (don't know if its the right one as I mention in my previous answer) I have uploaded the .blend file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had changed instancing from *Verts* to *None* and it showed up again in preview and render.

[image]

[image]